# HTML/CSS Background image doesn't scale in Safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari, scaling

I'm having a problem with background image scaling in Safari (specifically on the iPhone).

Here's how it looks on iPhone:

[image: screenshot]

Here's how it should look (at least):

[image: screenshot]

Here's the CSS code:

```css
#home {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
background-image: url(../img/header-bg.jpg);
background-position: bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
position: relative;
text-align: center;}

img {
vertical-align: middle;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto; }
```

I forgot to mention that "home" is the "id" of a `<section>` tag. The idea is to use an image background for this "#home" `<section>`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have safari, Try it:

```
#home {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    background-image: url(../img/header-bg.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't change anything when using Safari. On the other hand, this is how it looks on resized Chrome: http://s12.postimg.org/73kg90xm5/Untitled.png

Comment: Your 'test.php' link works fine, but I forgot to mention that "home" is the "id" of a <section> tag. The idea is to use an image background for this "#home" <section>. If I use this code for my <section> the image is grayed out in Safari.